# acquire double count data with rollup and having function

Tags: mysql

i hope there is somebody could help. i have a result query from table using rollup and group function. The result shows correct value as required. the problem occured when i have to line up in another condition..

here's my code :

```
select t.nama_konsumen, t.nama_material,  sum(t.netto) as Bobot, sum(t.volume), t.jenis_kendaraan, count(t.jenis_kendaraan) as kubik from t_penjualan_cash as t  group by t.nama_konsumen, t.nama_material, t.jenis_kendaraan with rollup
```

Here is the result

```
nama_konsumen   nama_material   sum(t.netto)  sum(t.volume)    t.jenis_kendaraan    kubik
ABOK            SPLIT 1X2         84398         62,5            COLT DIESEL           9
ABOK            SPLIT 1X2         84398         62,5               (null)             9
ABOK            SPLIT 2X3         7980          5,81            COLT DIESEL           1
ABOK            SPLIT 2X3         7980          5,81               (null)             1
ABOK            SPLIT 3X5           0           7,33            COLT DIESEL           1
ABOK            SPLIT 3X5           0           7,33               (null)             1
ABOK            SPLIT STOCK       54240         30,50           COLT DIESEL           4
ABOK            SPLIT STOCK       54240         30,50              (null)             4
ABOK               (null)         287704       213,36              (null)            33
```

what i want to show at the output is just like this..

```
nama_konsumen   nama_material   sum(t.netto)  sum(t.volume)    t.jenis_kendaraan    kubik
ABOK            SPLIT 1X2         84398         62,5            COLT DIESEL           9
ABOK            SPLIT 2X3         7980          5,81            COLT DIESEL           1
ABOK            SPLIT 3X5           0           7,33            COLT DIESEL           1
ABOK            SPLIT STOCK       54240         30,50           COLT DIESEL           4
ABOK               (null)         287704       213,36              (null)            33
```

i have no idea how to make it. and i would be happy if there somebody could help me.. thank you..

Comment: ' the problem occured when i have to line up in another condition' - is not clear what you mean.

Comment: sorry. what i mean is how output of the result is look like with my expected result.

Comment: One way is to put your entire query into a sub query and test to remove the sub totals in the outer query eg = where (nama_material is not null and  t.jenis_kendaraan is not null) or (nama_material is null and  t.jenis_kendaraan is null)

Comment: Ok. it's work.. thank's a lot.. :)